# Write a SQL Query for Multiple Database systems

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle11g

I would like to write a single Sql query which can run on multiple database system (Mysql, Sql Server, SQLLite).

Sql Query:

```
UPDATE table2 set table2.Name = table1.Name" join table1 on table2.Id = table1.Id
```

Comment: Any database system is very broad, you might have to limit the scope

Comment: NoSQL is a database system. Should we write a query that works for that as well?

Comment: MySQL does not follow ANSI standards so good luck with this.

Comment: @RickS to be fair every DBMS follows them to a point but then they all deviate into their own dialect in some situations. This is why creating truly database agnostic code is nearly impossible.

Comment: @SeanLange Fair enough, but at least for the above SQL statement, it does not follow SQL standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table2 
set table2.name = (select min(table1.name) 
                   from table1 
                   where table1.id = table2.id);
```

If `id` is unique in table1, then `min(name)` can be replaced by just `name`.

Comment: Don't think you can use a table + alias in the Update with SQL Server

Comment: Don't even need alias t2 (I see that JamieD77 edited my update now)

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing though, if there are ids in table2 that don't exist in table1. The original SQL Server version only updates rows with a join (if I've understood the syntax correctly), while the one here updates all rows in the table.

Comment: Thats true. Depending on what you want you could add this at the end: `where table2.id in (select id from table1)`